# Dataload Issue: Neo4j Down due to "UnderlyingStorageException: Error performing check point" error

Tags: neo4j

While loading data in to Neo4j, I am getting this below error and neo4j is not working properly. My memory configuration is - dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10G dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=10G dbms.memory.heap.max_size=30G $ulimit -n --> 50000 Please help me to fix this issue.

Background: We have developed talend etl jobs to fetch data from Postgres tables and load into Graph neo4j database. During execution of this jobs the neo4j gives below error and not working properly. Also, it claims to restart the neo4j application.

Can someone face this issue and help me out on this?

---

```
 2019-03-13 03:55:34.312+0000 ERROR Failed to start transaction. The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted. Please see database logs for more details.
    org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted. Please see database logs for more details.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.beginTransaction(ClassicCoreSPI.java:198)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransactionInternal(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:610)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:405)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.startTransaction(TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.<init>(TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.java:51)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransitionalPeriodTransactionMessContainer.newTransaction(TransitionalPeriodTransactionMessContainer.java:55)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.ensureActiveTransaction(TransactionHandle.java:213)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.commit(TransactionHandle.java:156)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.TransactionalService.lambda$executeStatementsAndCommit$1(TransactionalService.java:218)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:71)
        at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider.writeTo(StreamingOutputProvider.java:57)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1510)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.dbms.AuthorizationEnabledFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationEnabledFilter.java:123)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(CollectUserAgentFilter.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: The database has encountered a critical error, and needs to be restarted. Please see database logs for more details.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.DatabaseHealth.assertHealthy(DatabaseHealth.java:63)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.Kernel.newTransaction(Kernel.java:94)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.beginTransaction(ClassicCoreSPI.java:190)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Error performing check point
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointScheduler$1.constructCombinedFailure(CheckPointScheduler.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointScheduler$1.run(CheckPointScheduler.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.neo4j.helpers.NamedThreadFactory$2.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:109)
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationTimeoutException: Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 29701778, actual version: 29665951, wait timeout (ms): 600059
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:79)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:52)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:304)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:281)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.counts.CountsTracker.rotate(CountsTracker.java:155)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.flush(NeoStores.java:242)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.flushAndForce(RecordStorageEngine.java:465)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:160)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.checkPointIfNeeded(CheckPointerImpl.java:134)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointScheduler$1.run(CheckPointScheduler.java:64)
            ... 8 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationTimeoutException: Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 29710329, actual version: 29665951, wait timeout (ms): 600046
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:79)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:52)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:304)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:281)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.counts.CountsTracker.rotate(CountsTracker.java:155)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.flush(NeoStores.java:242)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.flushAndForce(RecordStorageEngine.java:465)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:160)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.checkPointIfNeeded(CheckPointerImpl.java:134)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointScheduler$1.run(CheckPointScheduler.java:64)
            ... 8 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationTimeoutException: Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 29725997, actual version: 29665951, wait timeout (ms): 600083
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:79)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:52)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:304)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:281)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.counts.CountsTracker.rotate(CountsTracker.java:155)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.flush(NeoStores.java:242)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.flushAndForce(RecordStorageEngine.java:465)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:160)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.checkPointIfNeeded(CheckPointerImpl.java:134)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointScheduler$1.run(CheckPointScheduler.java:64)
            ... 8 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationTimeoutException: Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 29727712, actual version: 29665951, wait timeout (ms): 600045
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:79)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:52)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:304)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:281)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.counts.CountsTracker.rotate(CountsTracker.java:155)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.flush(NeoStores.java:242)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.flushAndForce(RecordStorageEngine.java:465)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:160)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.checkPointIfNeeded(CheckPointerImpl.java:134)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointScheduler$1.run(CheckPointScheduler.java:64)
            ... 8 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationTimeoutException: Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 29729405, actual version: 29665951, wait timeout (ms): 600052
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:79)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:52)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:304)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:281)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.counts.CountsTracker.rotate(CountsTracker.java:155)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.flush(NeoStores.java:242)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.flushAndForce(RecordStorageEngine.java:465)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:160)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.checkPointIfNeeded(CheckPointerImpl.java:134)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointScheduler$1.run(CheckPointScheduler.java:64)
            ... 8 more
        Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationTimeoutException: Failed to rotate logs. Expected version: 29730976, actual version: 29665951, wait timeout (ms): 600072
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:79)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.RotationState$Rotation.rotate(RotationState.java:52)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:304)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.kvstore.AbstractKeyValueStore$RotationTask.rotate(AbstractKeyValueStore.java:281)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.counts.CountsTracker.rotate(CountsTracker.java:155)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.flush(NeoStores.java:242)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storageengine.impl.recordstorage.RecordStorageEngine.flushAndForce(RecordStorageEngine.java:465)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:160)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.checkPointIfNeeded(CheckPointerImpl.java:134)
            at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointScheduler$1.run(CheckPointScheduler.java:64)
            ... 8 more
```

Comment: What's the details about this in the logs?

Comment: What's the version of Neo4j? Did you try restarting as suggested in the error?

Comment: This issue happens again and again even after restarts. Neo4j version 3.1.4

Comment: can you upgrade your instance to a current version? Neo4j 3.1.x is 3 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the `neostore.counts.db.a/.b` files. Neo4j will rebuild them if they are missing.

Comment: We deleted these files as mentioned https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9807 and started server but its working for 1 or days only. Then we are facing same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please do the following (based on engineering feedback)

- upgrade to a recent version (like 3.5.3)
- check and possibly reduce your transaction batch sizes of your import jobs
- check the log for other errors that occur before these errors and also share them